# CSS Grid Layout Row Height 0px When Empty

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2">
        <div id="fullpage"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="child3"></div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
#container {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-rows: minmax(0, auto) auto minmax(0,75px);
}
```

The empty `child1` will have height filling the gap between the top screen and `child2`. I thought `minmax(0, auto)` will push child 1 into `0px` height?

What I want is when the child is empty or the element inside it are hidden, the height should be 0.

How can I achieve this?

---

### EDITED

```css
#container-wrapper {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(0,75px);
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container-wrapper">
        <div id="pageContainer" style="background-color:red">
          <div>test</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab-navigation" style="background-color:green">
          <!-- This should be 0px -->
        </div>
    </div>
```

The 2nd child should be height 0px. But this is wrong.

Comment: In your example, when #child1 is empty, the first row does get 0px in height. Can you tell a bit more about the undesired result you're getting?

Comment: When the child is empty, it will not set the height into 0. It is set to fill the gap between the top and the 2nd child (it can be like 300px). Same thing applies to the 3rd child. If its empty, it is set to 75 px. What i want is to set it to 0 when it is empty.

Comment: Sorry, I honestly still don't quite get it, maybe a working pen or snippet might help. But if you want child1 to take 0px if empty, you can give its grid-template-row be 0px, or minmax(0, min-content). Then child3 would take up to 75px of the remainder space (is this what you want?), and child2 will take whatever is left.

Comment: I just updated my code, please kindly check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like below:

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  height:200px;
  margin:10px;
  border:1px solid red;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
}

#container  > * {
  border:1px solid;
}
#child3 {
  max-height:75px;
}

#fullpage {
  height:100%;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child1"></div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="fullpage"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3"></div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="child1"> some content <br> here</div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="fullpage"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3"></div>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div id="child1"> some content <br> here</div>
  <div id="child2">
    <div id="fullpage"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="child3"> and also here </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `classes` instead `ids`?